# how do I get form_start and submit_row working in Silex?

Tags: twig, silex

The Symfony [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/twig_reference.html#form-start-view-variables) for twig mentions using form_start but when I try this in Silex I get this error

> Twig_Error_Syntax: The function "form_start" does not exist

Is it possible to use this in Silex?

Other form function like form_row() and form_widget() work.

Edit: I am using symfony/form dev-master (945f91ee8729a8f16e5d5c87c4920694e6b10475)
and symfony/twig-bridge 2.2.x-dev (6ddcb37ae4b7275c14baf365c7513b9ffdd6e31c)

Comment: Which version of silex, symfony/form and symfony/twig-bridge are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using a version of twig-bridge where it is not yet present.

`form_start` and `form_end` have been introduced by [commit d0b896](https://github.com/symfony/TwigBridge/commit/d0b896d41d14845986ac9a9035e9ceeaceaebc2e), and github tells us that 2.3.0 is the first release including it.

Also note that while you're using 2.2, you're browsing the docs for 2.3.

Comment: well spotted.  I had not realised I was viewing the wrong documentation.